# Icecast dont see mount point

Tags: icecast

I have a problem with mount points in icecast 2
the following is my config

```
<icecast>
<limits>
    <clients>100</clients>
    <sources>20</sources>
    <threadpool>5</threadpool>
    <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
    <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
    <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
    <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
    <burst-on-connect>10</burst-on-connect>
    <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
</limits>

<authentication>
    <source-password>admin</source-password>
    <relay-password>admin</relay-password>
    <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
    <admin-password>admin</admin-password>
</authentication>

<hostname>localhost</hostname>
<listen-socket>
    <port>8000</port>
</listen-socket>
<fileserve>1</fileserve>

<mount>
    <mount-name>/example-complex.ogg</mount-name>
    <max-listeners>100000</max-listeners>
    <dump-file>/tmp/dump-example1.ogg</dump-file>
    <fallback-mount>example2.ogg</fallback-mount>
</mount>



<paths>
<basedir>/opt/local/share/icecast</basedir>
<logdir>/opt/local/var/log/icecast</logdir>
<webroot>/opt/local/share/icecast/web</webroot>
<adminroot>/opt/local/share/icecast/admin</adminroot>
<alias source="/" dest="/status.xsl"/>
</paths>

<logging>
    <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
    <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
      <loglevel>3</loglevel>
      <logsize>10000</logsize>
</logging>

<security>
    <chroot>0</chroot>
    <changeowner>
        <user>djpasica</user>
        <group>admin</group>
    </changeowner>
</security>
</icecast>
```

and result is an empty mount point in icecast admin:

[image: icecast admin]

its after starting nicecast, I have a 1 mount point, but its an empty "/"

what i use:

```
icecast 2.3.2
nicecast 1.10.4
os: mac os x 10.7

nicecast config:Server Type: Icecast 2
Adress: localhost
Port: 8000
Mount Point: /example-complex.ogg
```

Comment: If you put a `</icecast>` at the end, does this resolve the issue?

Comment: No( i put it outside a block code, in real config he is

Comment: Can you please put the whole config in your question (replace any IPs and passwords with examples).

Comment: The same problem. My config - http://pastebin.com/QbRLWswc

Answer (score 1):

Hey it looks like you made an error configuring Nicecast. You might want to read the [following guide](https://wiki.xiph.org/Icecast_Server/Streaming_to_Icecast_with_Nicecast).

Please note that Nicecast has an built-in Icecast server, make sure you are not using this one. As well not that Nicecast for some reason will kill any running Icecast server on the same machine where Nicecast is started. So you have to first start Nicecast and only afterwards start your Icecast Server. (This should not happen anymore after you have disable the built-in server though)
Another issue I experience with some versions of Nicecast is that the Settings or at least some (like the Mountpoint Name) only take effect after restarting Nicecast.

Additionally make sure your Mountpoint name is **not** `/`, as this is an impossible mountpoint name (it conflicts with the web interface).

Comment: Technically not impossible, but rather inconvenient and requiring some additional configuration. So I'd file that under "advanced use case, not for beginners".

Comment: Good tip about `/` which I was about to attempt.  Instead I will use a sub-domain and nginx proxy.

Answer (score 0):

under **mount** and above **path** use

```
<mount>
    <mount-name>/myradio</mount-name>
    <password>mypassword</password>
    <public>1</public>
</mount>
```

Then in your encoder use /myradio as mountpoint and mypassword as password